# checkout всех веток через интерфейс Idea

Tags: java, git, intellij-idea, git-checkout

Добрый день, коллеги. Вопрос следующего характера: имеется многомодульный Java-проект. Всё дело контролируется Git и пишется в IDE Intellij Idea. В интерфейсе отображается каждый репозиторий и ветка, в которой он сейчас находится, и при чекауте переключается ветка только в одном проекте. В остальных остётся на той же, на которой и была. Получается, нужно сделать чекаут в каждом проекте в нужную ветку. Однако знаю, что можно сделать настройку так, чтобы при чекауте в одной ветке, все проекты автоматом переключались на ту же ветку, вопрос: как это сделать?

Comment: В идее есть отличный элемент интерфейса — консоль. Через нее подойдет решение? )

Comment: Пользуюсь консолью только при сложных операциях, типа отката веток и так далее.

Comment: А что если такой ветки не будет? Создать новую или проигнорировать?

Comment: таких случаев не бывает, при создании новой ветки, она создаётся для всех проектов с одним именем.

Comment: Хм, интересно. У меня сейчас немного похожий на это рабочий процесс, но я через python-invoke закодил жонглирование ветками. Пролистал настройки IDEA – не нашел такой опции, как вы описываете.

Comment: Кажется, вот оно: https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2012/08/git-branches-for-multi-root-projects/. Пойду испытаю его на 20 проектах )

Comment: Да, это оно. Спасибо.